# How do I remove non-numeric values from specific column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
['0' '58699' '443' '55420' '53' '1900' '80' '0xb058' '0xacd9' '0xc0a8'
 '0x1432' '0x0000' '123' '67' '5353' '2104' '547' '1' '53290' '4805'
 '2151' '58767' '27643' '58652' '64416' '62529' '55952' '57286' '64466'
 '50497' '0xa29f' '0x2d8e' '0x5b79' '0xb0eb' '0x87b5' '0x8efa' '0xd83a'
 '52142' '52138' '52920' '60162' '54214' '50848' '56986' '50367' '49460'
 '55963' '53327' '52022' '57400' '51755' '52834' '54183' '62724' '54871'
 '59845' '56309' '61878' '58326' '56686']
```

The column's unique values look like this. When I run:

```
df[df.DstPort.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())].set_index('DstPort')
```

It takes too long to process because it has 250k rows and I was not able to see the result too. My concern is that they are not numerical all. Like '443', '80' instead of 443, 80 and there are 0xb0eb. How can I get rid of 0xb0eb them and convert this column to int datatype?

Comment: No, as you might see from my question, I pasted the solution from there. And for my case, it took so long and in the end, it did not convert to numeric values. That is why I wanted to ask if there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are actually integers, just represented in a different base (base 16, also known as hexadecimal). The `int()` function takes an optional second argument for the base. We can check if a string consists only of numeric characters, and if so use 10 as the base, 16 otherwise:

```py
df.DstPort.apply(lambda x: int(x, 10 if x.isnumeric() else 16))
```

Comment: I do not want them like this actually. If I would have known what they mean, I could replace them like I did for https > 443, http>80. It is better than dropping them but I don't know. It is just an error after I convert pcap file to CSV.

I would like to remove them and change the values to int. Right now it is an object, "443" and with hex numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know why I just didn't convert them. They are not so many.
I converted all HEX to decimal and replace the values in the column. And then change datatype to int.
df['DstPort'] = df['DstPort'].replace(['0xb058','0xacd9','0xc0a8','0x1432','0x0000','0xa29f','0x2d8e','0x5b79','0xb0eb','0x87b5','0x8efa','0xd83a'],['45144','44249','49320','5170','0','41631','11662','23417','45291','34741','36602','55354'])

Comment: Wait, now I'm confused. It sounds like you *do* want to keep the hex numbers, but just convert them to integers. If so, my first solution does exactly that.

Comment: Yes actually, they might be important, so basically I just converted them to integer values, thanks for the help!